# Webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch freezes a modal with longer content in IOS 10

Tags: ios, css, scroll, modal-dialog, webkit

I have a strange problem with **webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch** property in IOS 10 - when the modal has longer content it gets 'stucked' or 'frozen' and not scrollable.
 First of all, I prevented the pinch zooming on the modal with JavaScript because I thought it caused the problem - no effect.
 I've also tried all the suggested fixes I could find, and still when the modal is longer, **sometimes** (not every time) it gets stucked when has been scrolled. 
This behaviour definitely comes from the **webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch** property, because when I remove it or set it to **auto**, the modal doesn't freeze but the scrolling becomes awful - not smoothly at all. 
Could someone suggest me a fix? Any help will be greatly appreciated.
This is part of the code:

```
.body.modal-open {
  position: fixed;
  width: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.modal-container {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
   left: 0;
   z-index: 2500;
   overflow-y: scroll;
   -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
   -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
   -webkit-perspective: 1000;

   &::before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
   }

  .modal {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 550px;
      z-index: 3000;
   }

}
```

Comment: does it help removing relative from .modal? (and applying the width, height, z-index on .modal-container?

Comment: seems not.. I had this working but it suddenly stopped working, I have no idea what changed.. maybe it worked in like iOs10.1 but not 10.2 ??

Comment: Hey, did you get a solution to this?